# What is __builtin_operator_new and how it works?

Tags: c++, clang, libc++

While going through libc++ code, I see ndk allocators `__allocate` function is calling `__builtin_operator_new`, but I could not found its definition in libc++ code.

By name it is evident that it is memory allocation function. But who implements it? Is it defined by compiler like clang, gcc? where can I find its definition?

Comment: Well clang is open source, so you can search its code to see if the symbol is there. Built-ins are by definition things _built in to_ the compiler, so it seems like a good place to look.

Comment: note that this is implementation details that are specific to the particular compiler you are using. If you want to write portable C++ you should pretend that you know nothing about them

Answer (score 8):

It's an intrinsic, defined implicitly by the compiler itself (hence why it's called a builtin). It's [documented](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-operator-new-and-builtin-operator-delete) on the language extension section for Clang:

> **__builtin_operator_new and __builtin_operator_delete**
>
> `__builtin_operator_new` allocates memory just like a non-placement non-class new-expression. This is exactly like directly calling the normal non-placement `::operator new`, except that it allows certain optimizations that the C++ standard does not permit for a direct function call to `::operator new` (in particular, removing new / delete pairs and merging allocations).
>
> Likewise, `__builtin_operator_delete` deallocates memory just like a non-class delete-expression, and is exactly like directly calling the normal `::operator delete`, except that it permits optimizations. Only the unsized form of `__builtin_operator_delete` is currently available.
>
> These builtins are intended for use in the implementation of `std::allocator` and other similar allocation libraries, and are only available in C++.

Comment: Most peculiar... Would you happen to know _why_ "removing new / delete pairs and merging allocations" is forbidden by the standard?

Comment: @nada - I'll have to dig into it to find out. But if you are curious it seems to me like it's worth posting a new question about it.

Comment: Thanks. I made a [short question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392330/why-does-the-c-standard-forbid-removing-new-delete-pairs-and-merging-allocat) about it.