# Why does the C++ standard forbid removing new / delete pairs and merging allocations as optimizations?

Tags: c++

The [clang docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-operator-new-and-builtin-operator-delete) cited in [an answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58391163/4850111) state

> that the C++ standard does not permit [...] removing new / delete pairs and merging allocations

as optimizations.

Why is that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the c++ standard does allow this and clang certainly performs such optimizations. However, I believe it wasn't always the case, so maybe it is onlyu relevant in c++03 mode.

Comment: Relevant: [Is the compiler allowed to optimize out heap memory allocations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31873616/580083).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31875487/560648 is the answer you want

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes you are correct plus clang could update its docs. It's in the standard since C++14 apparently.

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590885/optimization-of-raw-new-delete-vs-stdvector (Where the Standard is actually quoted in the answer!)